# Laravel adding details of two different user into there respected table

Tags: laravel

I want to store details as per user who is login and there ROLE that is whether they are teacher or student in respected table

In my Controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = Request::all();
        $this->validate($request,[
            'user_id'=>'required',
            'city'=>'required',
        ]);
        if (User::find($role,'teacher')){
            Teacher::create($input);
        }
        else{
            Student::create($input);
        }
          return redirect ('home');
    }
```

Now my Model for users

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password','role'
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function details()
{

    return $this->hasOne(['App\Teacher','App\Student']);
}
```

teachers model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'city',
];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

now students model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'city',
];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Comment: what's the error? what have you tried?

Comment: I want to store data in different table for different user role